# change the value of a multidimentional dict in python with nested dict enclosed in a list

Tags: python, dictionary

for example, let's say i have a dict like this:

```
bulk_details={
    "ad":'ad',
    'ad':[
        {'ad':'ad'},
        {'ad':'ad'}
    ]
}
```

I want to encrypt the values in the dict. i'm stuck at parsing the inner dicts inside the list

my code is this:

```
new_data = {key: {key_: encrypt(val_) for key_, val_ in (val.items() if type(val) is dict else val)} for key, val in (bulk_details.items() if type(bulk_details) is dict else bulk_details) }
```

Comment: what is the expected output ?

Comment: @SachinKukreja The same structure but with all `dict` `values` encrypted I guess.

Comment: Will you be able to read and understand your code in two days? Huge one-liners are satisfying in the very-short run, but they are bad code (in terms of maintainability).

Comment: Yes my frist reaction was that although it may seem "pythonic" to make that encryption a 1-liner, its not easy to understand, which makes it then not "pythonic".

Comment: Exactly, "one-liner" is not a pythonic property. Its just that often one-liners are very clear in python, and *that* makes them "pythonic".

Answer (score 4):

This is not nearly as compact as your one-liner, but it solves your problem and you can perhaps make it more compact:

```
bulk_details = {
    'ad':'ad',
    'ad2':
        [
            {'ad':'ad'},
            {'ad':'ad'}
        ]
}

def encrypt(to_encrypt):
    return '?' + to_encrypt + '?'

def encrypt_nested(dt):
    if isinstance(dt, dict):
        for key, value in dt.items():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                dt[key] = encrypt(value)
            else:
                encrypt_nested(value)
        return dt
    else: # elif isinstance(dt, list)
        for value in dt:
            if isinstance(value, str):
                value = encrypt(value)
            else:
                encrypt_nested(value)
        return dt

print(encrypt_nested(bulk_details))
# {'ad': '?ad?', 'ad2': [{'ad': '?ad?'}, {'ad': '?ad?'}]}
```

It iterates through a nested dict including arrays for any amount of levels using a recursing function.

Comment: Thanks. That fix my problem